# Getting wrong values from serial.read() connected to a Raspberry Pi

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, raspberrypi

I set up a serial connection and sending integers from a Raspberry Pi to an Arduino.

This is the Python code in my Raspberry Pi:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM2', 9600)
ser.write(str(x_value));
```

And this is the command line output for `x_value`:

> -38 -38 -38 -40 - 38 - 39 - 40 - 12 18 26 25 49...

They are x coordinate values I generated and they range from -100 to 100. And here's the Arduino code for receiving serial data:

```
int ByteReceived;

void loop() {
  while(1) {
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
      ByteReceived = (Serial.read());
      Serial.print(ByteReceived);
      Serial.print("\n");   
    }
  }
```

On the serial monitor I'm receiving these numbers:

> 46 45 51 48 45 53 52 45 49 52 45 52 55 55....

They are numbers between 40-60 and no way proportional to the values I sent from `serial.write`.

I'm really confused right now. Can someone help me to figure out what caused this problem?

Thank you so much.

Comment: You're receiving a different type than you're transmitting.

Comment: Learn the meaning of ASCII...

Comment: 46 45 51 48 45 53 52 45 49 52 45 52 55 55....
. - 3 0 - 5 4 - 1 4 - 4 7 7...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ser.write(str(x_value));
```

Writes the string representation of the integer `x_value`, which is a sequence of ASCII characters.

```
ByteReceived = (Serial.read());
Serial.print(ByteReceived);
```

Reads a character (byte) and prints to the value (again as a sequence of characters).

```
45 51 48 45 53 52 45 49 52 45 52 55 55....
```

`45` is ASCII character value for the character '-', `51` is the character '3', `48` is '0' and so on.

Cheers!